# How to add scroll bar to tkinter ttk notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, ttk

I've been using tkinter and ttk with python for a little while, but still rather new. I have a piece of code that generates a tkinter window. In that window I placed a notebook object, I plan on adding many labels into that notebook, and was wondering if there is a way to add a scroll bar to the notebook.

This is my code so far:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
import time

def browseL():
        filename=askopenfilename()
        ent1.insert(0,filename)

def browseR():
    filename=askopenfilename()
    ent2.insert(0,filename)


root=tk.Tk()
root.config(width=1350,height=550, bg='grey')
button=ttk.Button(root,text='Browse',command=browseL) 
button.place(x=500,y=130)
button2=ttk.Button(root,text='Browse',command=browseR) 
button2.place(x=700,y=130)

ent1=ttk.Entry(root)
ent2=ttk.Entry(root)
ent1.place(x=480,y=100)
ent2.place(x=680,y=100)

lab1=ttk.Label(root, text='Enter path to settings file #1', background='white')
lab2=ttk.Label(root, text='Enter path to settings file #2', background='white')
lab1.place(x=470,y=80)
lab2.place(x=670,y=80)

notebook=ttk.Notebook(root) 
notebook.place(x=1000,y=100) 

tab1=tk.Frame(root) 
tab1.config(width=100,height=100,background='white') 
notebook.add(tab1,text='tab1') 

root.mainloop()
```

Notice the notepad with one tab, that would be what I want to add a scroll bar to if it is possible.

And I am using python 3.4 if that helps

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can direct add a scrollbar only to Canvas, Text, and Listbox.  For anything else, you have to use a Canvas and put the widget on the canvas.  For instance, a 'scrolled frame' is a frame on a scrolled canvas.  It is tricky to get a scrolled widget-on-canvas right.

Comment: I used a Listbox with a scrollbar, and I am just adding to that it works perfectly thank you